# Setting value onClientClick() and Getting that on onClick()

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i have a asp:button and a asp:hiddenfield like this..

```
<asp:Button ID="btn_CreateContent" runat="server" Text="Upload" Height="25px" 
OnClientClick="UploadNewContent(event)" OnClick="btn_CreateContent_Click" />
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdn_ContentID"></asp:HiddenField>
```

I am setting value of "hdn_ContentID" onClientClick() with jQuery..

```
$('#ctl00_GspaceOnlinePlaceHolder_hdn_ContentID').val(SomeID);
```

and then i am trying to get that value onClick() on server side

```
protected void btn_CreateContent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string FileName = hdn_ContentID.Value;
}
```

but i am not getting that value.. i.e. getting FileName = "";

please help..

Comment: Do you get `SomeID` properly in javascript?

Comment: can you put the function `UploadNewContent`

Comment: Its a duplicate question.,Pls go through it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14930816/setting-value-onclientclick-and-getting-that-on-onclick

Answer (score 2):

Try to set an hidden-field value using following code

Try this

```
$('#<%=hdn_ContentID.ClientID %>').val(SomeID);
```

and

Make sure you are setting value in hidden-field by prompting an alert of hidden-field value by this

```
alert($('#<%=hdn_ContentID.ClientID %>').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

Better you try to create a html hidden field like this

```
<input type="hidden"name="hdGM" id="hdGM" />
```

Comment: Then how he will be able to access this hidden field on server?

Answer (score -1):

You can take the benefit of `ClientIDMode="Static"` as follows

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="hdn_ContentID">
</asp:HiddenField>
```

It will not change the client Id of the hidden field.

And then inside your function

```
 $('#hdn_ContentID').val(SomeID);
```

Also is there any specific reason of using `OnClientClick="UploadNewContent(event)"`
of passing **event** in the function?